# How can I pass a custom/dynamic product to the Woocommerce cart?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I have a Woocommerce site in which we're really only using Woocommerce for the shipping and taxes. We're not using it for inventory or any kind of product info.

I've developed a custom calculator that works fine with just HTML and JS. What I need to know is this: Can I pass a custom product into Woocommerce so it handles the checkout process?

If I can, are there any resources you can share?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: What do you mean "custom product"? The product needs to exist in the db and have an ID, then you can work with it

Comment: The main issue is they're a printer. So they don't track they're inventory with Woo. What about just a kind of "top-level" product? Like a book and then customize it from there? Custom product meaning custom number of pages, weight of paper, spine, color, etc.

Comment: Woo allows variable products, but you have to input the product variations before someone buys it so the product exists in the database. It's a way of protecting the site from a buyer injecting a custom product at whatever price they want. If you want to go the calculate-then-add-to-cart route without setting everything up in the database, you'll need to develop your own cart or find another CMS that supports that type of purchase.

Comment: Thanks for that @WebElaine. We're certainly not tied to Woocommerce. I was trying to save some steps, work and time. :)

Comment: Could you use WooCommerce API to create a product just for the customer?